# Reading a JSON string in Python: Receiving error " TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json, string, api, typeerror

I am trying to create a program that will get me current weather using the OpenWeatherMap API. I am new to coding in the sense of coding while receiving the data from the internet.

The error I receive is:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python Codes/Weather/CurrentTest3.py", line 7, in 
    temp_k = [record['temp'] for record in url2 ['main']] #this line should take down the temperature information from the .Json file
  File "/home/pi/Python Codes/Weather/CurrentTest3.py", line 7, in 
    temp_k = [record['temp'] for record in url2 ['main']] #this line should take down the temperature information from the .Json file
TypeError: string indices must be integers

I do not understand why I am getting this, my code is below.

```
from dateutil import parser #imports parser
from pprint import pprint #imports pprint
import requests #imports request
url = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?    q=london&APPID=APIKEY') #identifies the url address
pprint(url.json()) #prints .JSON information from address
url2 = url.json() #establishes .Json file as variable
temp_k = [record['temp'] for record in url2 ['main']] #this line should     take down the temperature information from the .Json file
print(temp_k) #prints the value for temperature
```

Comment: that's because `url2` is a list of dicts, not a dict.

Answer (score 0):

The value for `main` in your data is a dict, not a list of dicts. So there is no need to iterate through it; just access the temp value directly.

```
temp_k = url2['main']['temp']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this portion of `temp_k`, `record['temp']`.

This is the format of each variable `record`:

```
for record in url2 ['main']:
    print record

>> pressure
temp_min
temp_max
temp
humidity
```

It is a bunch of strings that you are trying to index as a dictionary, hence the string indices error. Just change the `temp_k` line to this:

```
temp_k = [url2['main'].get('temp')]

>> [272.9]
```